# How to fetch record in SQL using following use case

Tags: sql-server

I have a use case in which I have to get last five password from passwordhistory table,and there two column one md5 encrypted and second is hash ,after retrieving five records then I have to compared these column with new password,after moving them from md5 and hash function,if any record found then return true else return false.

```
DECLARE @UserID INT = 6 
DECLARE @Password NVARCHAR(200)='admin1952'


SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT TOP 5
                    ChangedPassword AS ChangedPassword ,
                    PasswordChangeHistory.Password_Hash AS Password_Hash
          FROM      PasswordChangeHistory WITH ( NOLOCK )
                    INNER JOIN [User] U WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON PasswordChangeHistory.UserID = U.Id
          WHERE     PasswordChangeHistory.UserID = @UserID
        )  AS result       
WHERE   PasswordChangeHistory.ChangedPassword = dbo.Encrypt_MD5(@Password)
```

Comment: Whats with the select top(5)? You know that the last row returned will be assigned to changedpassword if any rows are returned? @password is never assigned a value and it is passed to encrypt_md5? Are we missing some code?

Comment: What's wrong with your current attempt?

Comment: It doesn't return true/false.

Comment: Personally I think it just needs to do a count in the outer select and if count >=1 then 1 else 0.  `SELECT case when count(*) >= 1 then  1 else 0 end as PreviouslyUsed` and remove the other select values.

Comment: Problem is when i run this query its give error on where out select

Comment: My requirment is that i have to select last five password,then match on either change password or passwordhash ,if any record found then returns true,else false

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the subject line, here's one way you can do it (in psuedocode):

```
IF EXISTS( {your query to return a match from the last 5 passwords} )
  SELECT 1;
ELSE
  SELECT 0;
```

Or of course you can replace 1 and 0 with 'True' and 'False' if that's what you're actually looking for.

Comment: but my query does not return anything yet, I need that query that fulfill my need

Answer (score 0):

You can also try after the query:

```
if @@rowcount >0
   select 'user found'
else
   select 'user not found'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Is the solution of problem. as I have explain earlier I need five records from the table and then check new password with existing five record that if this new password has any matched with previous one then return false else return true.

```
DECLARE @UserID INT = 6 
DECLARE @Password NVARCHAR(200)= 'admin1958'
SELECT * FROM  
( SELECT    TOP(5)    ChangedPassword AS Changed ,PasswordChangeHistory.Password_Hash AS Password_Hash

          FROM      PasswordChangeHistory WITH ( NOLOCK )
                    INNER JOIN [User] U WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON PasswordChangeHistory.UserID = U.Id
          WHERE     PasswordChangeHistory.UserID = @UserID
          ORDER BY  PasswordChangeHistory.ID DESC

) AS result

WHERE result.Changed= dbo.Encrypt_MD5(@Password) or result.Password_Hash = dbo.Encrypt_SHA2(@Password)
```

Comment: If this is the answer, please mark it as such to close the question.

Comment: I do not permission for today.will do this tomorrow.